# Uncaught Error: Script error for: bootstrap

Tags: magento2

guys I'm getting the following error "Error not detected: Script error for: bootstrap
", and my dropdown doesn't work. How can I fix this? I'm trying to use a bootstrap.js class but it doesn't work.

my code: default_head_blocks.xml

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js" />
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" />
    <script src="requirejs/require.js" />
    <script src="mage/polyfill.js" />



    <css src="mage/calendar.css" />

    <css src="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <css src="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"/>

    

</head>
```

Comment: how did you include the js file? can you please add your code in the question?

Comment: I added the code